# Nouveau driver on Notebook with only integrated Intel graphics

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, nouveau

I've been experiencing a black screen after waking up from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04.
While looking for a solution, I found that for some people the issue was the nouveau driver. I thought "that can't be it" since I don't even have a dedicated graphics card (just the integrated of an i7 8550U).
However, I checked the output of

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i nouveau
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                                            2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                                                     amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:i386                                             2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                                                     i386         Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04                             1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1                                                          amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
```

Hence, I'm wondering what these are needed for and if I should keep or remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many versions of those packages, for many GPUs, so while you could delete the ones you don't need, they'll probably reappear as something had them added as a depencdency in the first place.  Don't bother with deleting them unless you are really critical on space.

Answer (score 0):

Just because they are installed doesn't mean they are loaded or in use.

To check and see if they are in use:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

To see if they are needed:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```